# Error while using sh script

Tags: shell, sh

I am using `sh` shell due to restriction of unavailability of `bash` shell. Below piece of code runs fine on a `bash` shell but throws error while running on `sh` shell.

```
if [[ -n  $(grep -i "${RSA_BACKUP[iter]}: OK" $BACKUP_HASH_TRACK) ]]
```

> error: /etc/backup_infra.sh: line 79: syntax error: bad substitution

Comment: What are the values of the variables you are using? Without those proper values, your input is not verifiable and therefore cannot be provided with a proper solution.

Comment: There are two elements of your code which are bashisms and would not work in a POSIX shell (assuming your `sh` is POSIX, which you haven't confirmed). The first is `[[`. Instead of using this, rewrite your script to use traditional tests. `man test` for details of what's available on your platform. The second is your use of an array. Bash supports arrays. POSIX shell does not. You'll need to provide greater context in your question if you want help coding your way around this.

Comment: @ghoti: Totally in agreement with you. As you have seen OP's post was not verifiable to the least, we had no idea what his requirement was and what his values for the variables held( I even posted a comment requesting for information), but the least suggestion/help with that information I could give was recommending usage of [ which I did so

Comment: @@Indra: If only you let us know what are the values of the variable (or) what is your intention with that particular `if` construct, we could help with `sh` equivalent of your code.

Comment: ok, I have an array of strings which is RSA_BACKUP[] , now I need to find the following  "RSA_BACKUP[idx]: OK" in a file while traversing a list of file

Comment: @Indra: Aside from the fact that you haven't yet answered the issue about *sh* yet, as explained by ghoti, even in your bash code, you don't index the array by a number, but by a string, i.e. use it as associative array. Are you sure that this is what you intended?

Comment: @Indra: It is better if you can explain in the question with some sample values of array and how would you like to match it

Answer (score 0):

The script that you are trying to run requires Bash (at at least version 4.0).  This is because it uses

1. Associative arrays (`${RSA_BACKUP[iter]}`).
2. `[[ ... ]]` instead of `[ ... ]`.

Many shells use the `[[ ... ]]` syntax nowadays, and some, like `bash`, are able to understand it even though they are invoked as `sh`. The `dash` and `ash` shells, however, do not.

But the main issue is the associative array.  The problem you're facing now is to either

1. completely rewrite the script to avoid both arrays and associative arrays, or
2. arrange with an installation of `bash` for which this script was written.